# How to explain CSS Float in general language?

Tags: css

How to explain CSS Float in general language (not Programming) ? Is there any real life example to take a example to explain CSS Float?

Is there any Slideshow in very simple way to explain float?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explain it exactly like it sounds :)

It's called float because an element "floats" like a boat does.  Consider the rest of the content water and the object a boat...the object displaces a certain amount of space and the water (other content) wraps around it.  In the few times I've had to convey this property's meaning, this was the explanation that "got it across".

That doesn't cover the cross-browser quirks like IE floats, but for a general explanation, it works.  For a *complete* explanation, I still think this is the best resource out there: [simple tutorials on CSS floats](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/).

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself.

Comment: then how to explain Flow? Normal and Out of flow?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: You mean with respect to positioning, e.g. absolute being out of the normal flow?  Or only in context of float-flow?  There are a few properties that affect flow.

Comment: For IE floats, you could say that the boats have sails, and they can be moved randomly by the wind :)

Comment: @Nick - and what is real world example for positioning?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: That one's not as simple IMO, I would say "fixed" is "fixed", right where your eye sees it, "absolute" is in an "absolute" spot from the top/left (with respect to *something*), "relative" is "relative" to where it normally would be, "static" is "steady", in-the-flow, and "inherit", well, inherits.

Comment: @- For float - can we also take a example of Slope way? everything will go where slope goes

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: Not really, in terms of flow, the same boat example applies, in most cases the element will "float" to the top (and right or left after that) of the container it's in...notice I didn't say page, but the container it's in.  If you're dealing with IE and want to float something left and something right in the same container (we'll call it a lake), you need to float both boats in the CSS explicitly, or one's taking on water, because IE's a special kid.

Comment: @Nick-Are you talking about all IE version till 8?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: Correct, IE8 handles this correctly, when it's not in IE7 rendering mode that is.

Comment: @Nick - For what purpose `Float` were created?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: To float things, like anything in the spec there's no one reason, there are dozens...otherwise it wouldn't have made it into the spec.  Any time you want to position an element and have things flow around it, you can float, any example of this is a valid reason for it.  I often use it when I need something all the way to right right for some reason, it the simplest way to do it across many layout scenarios (though I have the luxury of not caring about IE6, some may not).

Comment: I mean float were made for Layouts or developer found this way? and What was the purpose to made Positioning?

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: You'll have to ask whoever added it to the spec, all of this was for layouts, I know how I use it today, but that's a very different browser ecosystem than when these things were added to CSS, what the reasoning of the original authors was? I have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

The [float property](https://kolosek.com/css-float/) specifies how the element will be placed **to the left or right of the parent container**. After the float property is added to the element, it is moved either to the left or right side until it touches the edge of the container element or another floated element. The float property **implies the use of block elements**.

The property can have the next values:

- **left** - the element floats to the left of its container element
- **right** - the element floats to the right of its container element
- **none** - the element does not float