# CSS Float: Why is float applied to the element just prior to the element to be floated?

Tags: css, css-float

There is something about the CSS "float" property that has always confused me. Why is the "float" attribute applied to the element just prior to the element you want floated?

To help visualize my question I created the following jsFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Ubutb/12/

In the example the float attribute is applied to the navigation `<div>` rather than the content `<div>`. I would have thought that the float needed to be applied the the 
"content" `<div>` elements since these are the items you want to "float" out of the normal flow of the page. I am obviously missing something. Could someone explain it better than I am understanding? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"float:left;"` means that the div is pushing against the parent `<div>`'s "left wall".. and when the next `"float:left;"` div is added in the same container, it will be pushed to the left, and hit the "Right wall" of the first div.... like a puzzle.

The container's width decides if the second `"float:left;"` div has enough room to be laid out beside the first one, or if it's going underneath.

You can most often have 3 divs floating left in a container, if each div is 33% wide, and has no margins, and they end up on a nice line. But if the width is 34%, one will go underneath..

That's the easiest explanation of a floating div.. and of course the other way round when it's float right.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `float: {position}` CSS, you're telling that element to "Float on the {position} side of its parent element". The content ones are behaving as normal, as if the navigation `div` wasn't even there, because it's the navigation you've instructed to float out of the way of other elements.

Comment: So the navigation DIV will respect the "header" DIV and only float as far up in it's own container DIV as the "header" DIV allows?

Comment: It had always confused me as to why the "content" DIVs floated to the left of the "navigation" DIV when they did not have any `float` attribute applied. However, if I am understanding correctly, they are aligning to the right of the "navigation" DIV because it is in the way and they want to be underneath the "header" DIV, which is the normal flow. Does this make sense?

Comment: That's the thing though - the content divs aren't floating - the navigation div is floating _in front of_ the other elements. Think of your elements as a stack of objects in a box. When you make one 'float' (by pulling it out the stack and towards you), the others drop down to fill its place (in this case, drop up because HTML is top-down). Those other boxes aren't floating, they're just filling up the space - it's the one you pulled out that's floating.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a good explanation of why floats work the way they do? Here are some good write-ups:

- [All About Floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) from CSS-Tricks
- [CSS Float Theory](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/) from Smashing Coding
- [How to explain CSS Float in general language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996303/how-to-explain-css-float-in-general-language) from StackOverflow

**My own explanation:** The floated element is indeed the one floating. The elements next to it are doing what's called "wrapping".

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ubutb/13/)

The floating position is relative to the "container" a.k.a. "parent" (in this case, where there is no container, the latter is the whole body)

Comment: Also, depending on how your content is laid out, you can use something like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ubutb/21/).
It uses float:right

Comment: It was not that I didn't know how to accomplish the layout but rather I was trying to understand why it worked that way. Thanks for the example though!